# Error while drawing a clock using turtle module

Tags: python3, tkinter

My code:

```
import turtle
wn =turtle.Screen()
te=turtle.Turtle()
te.shape("turtle")
te.left(90)
for i in range(12):
  te.penup(100)
  te.right(30)
wn.mainloop()
```

The [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhok7.png): Type error occurred in terminal. Please help. I am beginner in Tkinter graphics.

Comment: `penup` takes no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, [`penup` does not take any arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.penup). So, I do not know what you are trying to do, but your code may be corrected as in the example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import turtle
wn=turtle.Screen()
te=turtle.Turtle()
te.shape("turtle")
te.penup()
te.setpos((0,250))
te.pendown()
te.right(-15)
for i in range(12):
  te.right(30)
  te.forward(100)
wn.mainloop()
```